# Could intelligent parasaurolophuses form a primarily sound-based language?

Tags: language, dinosaurs

I was thinking about how [parasaurolophuses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parasaurolophus?) could make sounds using their cranial crests. Then I thought that if they were intelligent enough, maybe they could create a spoken (honked? bellowed?) language based on the sounds made with their crests. So:

**How many distinguishable sounds could parasaurolophuses make, and is that enough to form a language?**

Bonus question: How could parasaurolophuses from different places have different “accents”? Could they, even?

Comment: Kind of new here - please correct me if I’m doing something wrong :)

Comment: Welcome. Perhaps the spelling of Parasaurolophus in the title. Then to the question, sure, if you want, it's your world. But you've not given us any problem to solve. We like problem solving and we get grumpy if there isn't one (well, some of us do). Perhaps re-work the question to present us with a challenge - what difficulties do you foresee that we might help you overcome?

Comment: Well, mainly I’m not sure hope many sounds you need to have a language, and how many sounds parasaurolophuses can make. Thanks :)

Comment: Could you perhaps read the [ask] section of the [help] and [edit] your question accordingly. We deal with single focused questions.

Comment: Oh, and the spelling in the body of the question - always worth proof-reading as you go. :)

Comment: Bear in mind that reptilian hearing is nothing anywhere near as acute as mammalian, they don't possess the same apparatus. The frequency and dynamic range would be severely limited compared to ours. So, you might need to modify that too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have no idea what range of sound qualities a parasaurolophus could make, but as long as they can vary their pitch, that's good enough for encoding a language. We know this because whistle registers exist--the most famous being Silbo Gomero, a whistled encoding of Spanish. Whistle registers rely solely on the combination of amplitude modulation and single-channel pitch modulation, and they work just fine for humans. So if another animal can do at least that much, they definitely have enough range to use an acoustic language--presuming their brain capacity is up to it.

For reference, human languages have been documented with as few as 11 distinct phonemes, so the parasaurolophuses don't even need *all that much* range in controllable pitch/amplitude variation to produce enough distinctions for a practical language.

Comment: Also to have some amount of language wouldn't even require 11 phonemes, that's just the fewest we've seen for human language

Answer (score 4):

The range of sounds used to create human languages come from the vocal chords, but also the combination of the tongue, teeth, lips and cheeks. By changing the shape of the mouth's opening, you can produce a range of tones, while changing the pathway of air through the inside of the mouth introduces the distinction between consonants and vowels. By combining these two, a truly vast variety of sounds are made possible, and from that, a wealth of potential languages and accents can spring.

However, we know from birds, especially corvids such as crows and parrots, that it is possible to mimick these sounds with only a tongue and a beak, no teeth, lips or cheeks required. They do not even have a vocal chord, exactly - birds have an organ called a syrinx, similar to our larynx in purpose but with a different shape and location in the body.

Parasaurolophus as it existed had teeth and a beak, but there's a lot we have to guess about. It appears to have had muscles in its mouth similar to cheeks but not quite cheeks, and a tongue that probably wasn't very mobile. It also had the big crest on its skull, which likely was used to amplify the sound of its calls. Some researchers believe that the dinosaur could send air through the longer passage of its skull, making the voice deeper, louder and more resonant. Interestingly, it appears that this passage went through the nostrils, meaning that the sounds of the horn might not be manipulable into consonant and vowel sounds by the tongue. This does create a new method of manipulation, however, in opening or closing the mouth while 'singing' through the crest, creating a wide variety of tones through mouth shape and a wholly different sound when only snorting through the nostrils.

All in all, I think that there is room for a language here. For an easy way in, just imagine that the parasaurolophus had or evolved to have a versatile tongue, and say that it can make sounds the same way a parrot does. As long as it is intelligent, those sounds could conceivably evolve into a language. Even without the tongue, however, the variation in tone between mouth voice and horn voice would probably be enough to found a language on.